# How can I prevent the Mormon Church from corrupting my son?

Tags: development

Yesterday my son told me about a club he joined at school. I'm worried it's a puppet organization for the Mormon Church. How do I dissuade him from being indoctrinated?

Comment: How old is your son? The answers would be different for 6 year old or an 18 year old.

Comment: If you still have a question after reading the linked post, please edit your post to specify and flag it for a moderator to evaluate for reopening. Thanks.